# Indexing without having to type a word twice

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I'm trying to speed things up.
**IF** I type

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{document}
\noindent  Hey! \index{baby}!, \\
there ain't no easy way out \\
Hey! I!\\
won't \index{back down}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

**THEN** the result is
[image]
But **IF** I *double type*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\begin{document}
\noindent  Hey! baby\index{baby}!, \\
there ain't no easy way out \\
Hey! I!\\
won't back down\index{back down}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

**THEN** the result is
[image]

I don't want to have to type words twice twice...-.-

Comment: `\newcommand\zz[1]{#1\index{#1}}  ... \zz{baby}`

Comment: Thanks!! There wouldn't happen to be a way to nest? such as ```Climbing up on \zz{\zz{Solsbury} \zz{Hill}} ``` prints ```Hill, Solsbury``` in the **index**. IF I type ```Solsbury Hill\index{\zz{Solsbury} \zz{Hill}}```, THEN ```Hill, Solsbury, Solsbury Hill``` gets printed in the **index**. But that is double typing :)

Comment: probably is possible but I wouldn't. diminishing returns, it will be tricky to code and harder to understand, there are othe rthings you might want eg `\index{foo@textit{foo}}`  it would be possible to invent some way of specifying optional styling but again i wouldn't just have a simple command for the simple cases.

Comment: I see. I also noticed that nesting ```\index{\zz{A} \zz{B}``` prints ```A,2  A B,1  B,2``` so it adds a page number to the inner ```\zz```

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't error? `\index` in the argument of `\index` can't really do anything useful.